# Obtaining probability density function from a cumulative distribution function

Tags: plotting

I have some difficult times to obtain the density function of

```
mytemp1[x_] :=(1.0248065725187662*^-51*(2.6767526314134802*^50*Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*
 Boole[x == -0.23543491335723254] + 2.6767526314134802*^50*
 Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*Boole[x > -0.23543491335723254] + 
1.7063501249740173*^50*Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*Boole[x > 0.372854069211365] + 
1.0370049886441548*^50*Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*Boole[x >= -1.1256841258094925] - 
1.1012805355466846*^50*Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*
 Boole[Inequality[-0.23543491335723254, Less, x, LessEqual, 0.372854069211365]] + 
4.785811934774179*^50*Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*
 Boole[-1.1256841258094925 < x < -0.23543491335723254] - 3.8125196967494504*^50*
 Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*
 Boole[Inequality[-0.23543491335723254, Less, x, LessEqual, 0.372854069211365]]*
 Erf[0.6397548845960749 - 0.00011639314699198901*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]] - 
5.853648834898374*^50*Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]*
 Boole[-1.1256841258094925 < x < -0.23543491335723254]*Erf[0.9428090415937657 - 0.0000789800278057105*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]] - 
1.1567549958229337*^51*Boole[x > 0.372854069211365]*
 Erf[6.862076490981416*^-27*Abs[1.373941317665092*^26 - 1.1509639670952538*^22*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]] + 
9.690248788879874*^46*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]*Boole[x > 0.372854069211365]*
 Erf[6.862076490981416*^-27*Abs[1.373941317665092*^26 - 1.1509639670952538*^22*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]]))/Abs[2.666666666699766 - 0.00022338925295887992*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]] - Piecewise[{{0.44454379593695487*Erfc[0.9428090415937657 + 0.0000789800278057105*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]], x > 0.3728540691229937}, {0.006247666477402043, x == 0.3728540691229937}, {0.10627295280972776, x == -1.1256841258094925}, {-5.280090347178013*^-26*(-1.1301437402263126*^25 + 1.1361278699382123*^25*
   Erf[0.9428090415937657 + 0.0000789800278057105*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]), -1.1256841258094925 < x < -0.23543491342534603}, {-1.0560180694356026*^-25*(-3.720166687592846*^24 + 3.6998374896882866*^24*
   Erf[0.6397548845960749 + 0.00011639314699198901*Sqrt[7.5873653*^7 + 6.7402259*^7*x]]), -0.23543491342534603 < x < 0.3728540691229937}, {0.013583062452533764, x == -0.23543491342534603}}, 0.]
```

I use the code

```
fx1[x_] = D[mytemp1[x], x]
```

when I evaluate it I get for example

```
fx1[4]

6.079153234720428*^-6 + 3.2335575968221936*^-52*(1.1087414761386247*^50 -4.5032354526767183*^49*Derivative[1][Abs][-1.6329043751585144*^26] - 1.5619432062485812*^50*Derivative[1][Abs][-3.1692850423505785]) +0.08635812743449818*Derivative[1][Abs][-3.1692850423505785]
```

Which is not a real number.

What am I doing wrong or what is missing in my way? I am not able to either plot or evaluate  $fx1[x]$. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: It still doesnt help. I was aware of it and with only $_$ not $:$ , I was getting $fx1[9]=6.07915*10^-6 + 
 3.23356*10^-52 (1.10874*10^50 - 
    4.50324*10^49 Derivative[1][Abs][-1.6329*10^26] - 
    1.56194*10^50 Derivative[1][Abs][-3.16929]) + 
 0.0863581 Derivative[1][Abs][-3.16929]$  the output is not a real value.

Comment: @rm-rf I edited the question.

Comment: Ok, I was going to reopen it but kguler has already done it. Good luck!

Comment: @rm-rf and kGULER thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ex-post replace `Abs'[...]` terms with `Sign[...]`:

```
fx0[x_] = D[mytemp1[x], x] /. (Abs' -> Sign);

fx0[#] & /@ Range[10]
(* {0.114698, 0.0894219, 0.0700865, 0.0547306, 0.0424906, 0.0327863, 0.0251506, 
    0.0191887, 0.0145676, 0.0110091} *)
Plot[fx0[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Or, use `PiecewiseExpand` that seems to prevent the `Abs'` issue (but it is much slower):

```
ClearAll[mytemp2, fx2];
mytemp2[x_] := PiecewiseExpand[mytemp1[x], Reals];

fx2[x_] = D[mytemp2[x], x]
```

[image]

```
fx2[#] & /@ Range[10]
(* {0.114698, 0.0894219, 0.0700865, 0.0547306, 0.0424906, 0.0327863, 0.0251506, 
    0.0191887, 0.0145676, 0.0110091} *)

Plot[fx2[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Really appreciated.

Comment: @seyhmus, glad it solved your problem. Thank you for the Accept.